# What's the Media query for One Plus X device?

Tags: css

I don't know where to find the Media query for this device, my client is using one plus x. He have some responsive issue,

Comment: i have given @media screen and (max-width: 767px) this seems to be working on my mobile and others mobile, but my client have OnePlus X mobile, he's saying that he cant see any changes, so i got confused what might be the media query for that device

Comment: The thing is i'm just not need this for website, i need this for gmail emailer rendering...so i dont wanna use JS

Comment: If he cannot see any changes it's not about media query, it' s about cache. So in order to fix it you have to add something in link of your style.css in head tag. E.g <link href="style.css?v=2.2"> and than ask if he can see changes.

Comment: its gmail emailer..so obviously it would render every time when u open the mail.....that's not about cache... I just need media query and resolution of OnePlus X device....It would be helpful if anyone knows

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What exactly are the issues your client has, and why do think a new media query would solve those?

Answer (score 0):

**OnePlus 6T Media Query**

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.625),
  only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2.625),
  only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.625/1),
  only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.625),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 402dpi),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 2.625dppx) { 
    //Your CSS here
}
```

**Reference:** https://vizdevices.yesviz.com/devices/oneplus-6t/